# 2019 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Chess's [first moderator election](https://chess.stackexchange.com/election/1) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied and the two new moderators are:

[image: Brian Towers] [image: Glorfindel]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://chess.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly—please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

Also, please join me in thanking ETD and Daniel who will be stepping down as moderator.

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://chess.stackexchange.com/election/1), or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/5753052428500992/0).

Answer (score 6):

Congratulations @BrianTowers! I'm looking forward to work with you and the rest of the team (read: Andrew).
Thank you @ETD and @Daniel for all the work you've done so far.
Thanks to @Phonon, @fuxia and @Brandon_J for participating, and good luck next time.
And above all thanks to all the voters who made this election possible.

Comment: Thanks @Glorfindel. It looks to me that you have been carrying most of the load for some time. Good that you are now a full time mod. Thanks to all who took part whether standing for election or voting. Democracy is important. Those who have been carrying out mod duties by virtue of having relatively high reputation, please don't stop! Your efforts are still useful and much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Congratulation! But ... this community is quite small, why do we need so many moderators?

Comment: The election was triggered because two of the three previous moderators were standing down. This just restores the number of moderators to three.

Answer (score 1):

Congratulations @BrianTowers and @Glorfindel: thanks for all your work to come.